# Подсчет символов в параграфах со вставкой переменой PHP

Tags: php

Статья разбита параграфами данный код после каждого третьего параграфа вставляет переменную с похожим контентом, но встречаются небольшие параграфы по 300 символов, а то и меньше.

```
$content = [
    '<div>Контент после 1-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 2-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 3-их трёх параграфов</div>',
];

$str = '<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>';

preg_match_all('~<p>.*?</p>~', $str, $arr);
$arr = empty($arr[0]) ? [] : $arr[0];

foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    if ((++$k % 3) == 0) {
        echo $item . current($content);
        next($content);
    } else {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Подскажите как можно реализовать если в параграфе содержится меньше 1000 символов, символов то добавлялось к нему еще несколько параграфов, но так чтобы они не объединялись, а шли также параграфом до 1000 символов или чуть более и как набирается количество 1000 или больше символов происходила вставка переменой.

Comment: Да просто накапливай свои параграфы в буфере и контролируй текущий размер, типа `foreach($arr as $item){$buf.=$item;if($buf.length>1000){echo $buf.current($content);next($content);$buf=''}}`

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего будет сделать буферную переменную, как заметил @akina

Ниже валидный код. Но вообще советую избавиться от магических чисел, таких как 3, 1000 и подобных им. Лучше используйте переменные, или опишите этот код в виде функции, а числа передавайте как параметры. Это сделает ваш код чище, понятнее и надёжнее.

```php
$content = [
    '<div>Контент после 1-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 2-ых трёх параграфов</div>',
    '<div>Контент после 3-их трёх параграфов</div>',
];

$str = '<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p><p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p><p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>';

preg_match_all('~<p>.*?</p>~', $str, $arr);
$arr = empty($arr[0]) ? [] : $arr[0];

$length_buffer = 0;

foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    // используем mb_ функцию для верного подсчёта
    // количества символов кириллицы
    $length_buffer += mb_strlen($item);
    if ((++$k % 3) == 0 && $length_buffer >= 1000) {
        // обязательно надо обнулить
        $length_buffer = 0;
        echo $item . current($content);
        next($content);
    } else {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```